# Flutter: disable sliverAppBar padding animation

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to attach custom menu bar (full width) to the `sliverAppBar` widget so that it will stick to the bottom of sliverAppBar background and will be always visible.

To solve this I've put `Row` widget into `FlexibleSpaceBar.title` parameter but now I have one unexpected problem.

When I wrap anything inside `FlexibleSpaceBar.title` parameter into a `Row` widget it starts to animate overflowed padding. Also it expands `Row` widget outside screen bounds. That was unexpected behavior.

I don't want to shrink title padding or resize title on SliverList scroll.

[image: You can't watch [screencast here][1]]

```
SliverAppBar(
  expandedHeight: 200.0,
  floating: false,
  pinned: true,
  elevation: 0.0,
  flexibleSpace: SafeArea(child: // <-- SafeArea doesn't work for FlexibleSpaceBar.title in this case
    FlexibleSpaceBar(
      background: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Image.asset(
            'assets/images/store.png',
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            width: 120,
            height: 120,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      collapseMode: CollapseMode.none,
      titlePadding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(start: 100, bottom: 0), // <-- have to add 100 to padding to keep in safe area on the screen
      title: Row( // <-- animation enables by default if wrapped in a Row widget
        children: [
          Icon(Icons.menu, size: 40, color: Colors.white,),
        ]
      )
    )
  )
),
```

How to disable this shrink, size and animation in sliverAppBar for FlexibleSpaceBar title?

Answer (score 1):

I've just solved this problem by adding one more sliverAppBar instead of using FlexibleSpaceBar.title for this purpose.

```
SliverAppBar( // <-- just hiding logo
  expandedHeight: 200.0,
  floating: false,
  pinned: true,
  elevation: 0.0,
  flexibleSpace: SafeArea(child:
    FlexibleSpaceBar(
      background: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Image.asset(
            'assets/images/store.png',
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            width: 120,
            height: 120,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    )
  )
),
SliverAppBar( // <-- custom sticky menu bar
  floating: false,
  pinned: true,
  elevation: 0.0,
  flexibleSpace: SafeArea(child:
    FlexibleSpaceBar(
      ...
    )
  )
),
```